# Prove that either $\left | p \right |=\left | q \right |$ or $(p, q) = 1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, prime-numbers

Suppose $p$ and $q$ are primes. Prove that either $\left | p \right |=\left | q \right |$ or $(p, q) = 1$.

Hint from a teacher: "Remember that primes have exactly four divisors."

Here's what I got:

Let $D(p)$ be a set of all divisors of $p$ and $D(q)$ be a set of all divisors of $q$. Then $D(p) = \left \{ 1, -1, p, -p \right \}$ and $D(q)= \left \{ 1, -1, q, -q \right \}$.

$\forall a \in D(p): a| \left | q \right | \Rightarrow D(p) = D(q)$

Then  $\left | p \right |=\left | q \right |$

I'm not sure whether this could stand as a proof of this part of the statement: "$\left | p \right |=\left | q \right |$ ".

Comment: "$a$ divides $|q|$ implies $D(p)=D(q)$" is a non sequitur. For any primes $p$ and $q$, $1\in D(p)$, $1$ divides $|q|$, but that does not mean the divisors of $p$ coincide with the divisors of $q$.

Comment: Hint: to prove "$P$ or $Q$", one can argue by cases. "If $P$, we are done. Otherwise, assume not($P$), and we want to prove $Q$. So argue that if $|p|=|q|$ you are done; then assume that $|p|\neq|q|$ and try to prove that this means that $\gcd(p,q)=1$.

Comment: $\color{#c00}{1<d}:=(p,q)\mid p,q \Rightarrow d\mid p\overset{p\ \rm prime}\Rightarrow d =|p|.\,$ Similarly $\,d =|q|.\,$ So $\,\color{#c00}{(p,q)\neq1}\Rightarrow |p| = |q|\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $p$ and $q$ are distinct prime numbers.

Since $p$ is prime, it has exactly four divisors: 1, $p$, $-1$, and $-p$.

Similarly, since $q$ is prime, it also has exactly four divisors: 1, $q$, -1, and $-q$.

If $\left|p\right|=\left|q\right|$, it implies that either $p=q$ or $p=-q$, but not both.

If $p=q$, then $(p,q)=p=q$, which is not equal to 1. Thus, $\left|p\right|=\left|q\right|$ implies that $(p,q) \neq 1$.

If $p=-q$, then $(p,q)=(-q,-q)=q$, which is not equal to 1 either. Thus, $\left|p\right|=\left|q\right|$ implies that $(p,q) \neq 1$.

If $\left|p\right|\neq\left|q\right|$, then $(p,q)=1$ because there are no common factors between $p$ and $q$ other than 1.